# How do I convert excel file to pdf file

Tags: phpspreadsheet

How do I convert excel file to pdf file. I have phpspreadsheet and tcpdf installed. But How do I make phpspreadsheet use Tcpdf . Am getting this error

> Fatal error: Class 'TCPDF' not found in
>   /home3/user1/public_html/site.com/downloads/phpspreadsheet/vendor/phpoffice/phpspreadsheet/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Pdf/Tcpdf.php
>   on line 21

here is my code

```
 require '../phpspreadsheet/vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;





$spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load('testxl.xlsx');

$class = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Pdf\Tcpdf::class;
\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::registerWriter('Pdf', $class);
$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Pdf');

$writer = new \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Pdf\Tcpdf($spreadsheet);
$writer->save("demo.pdf");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass $spreadsheet and writer type to createWriter(). Example of pdf writer type that can be used in phpspreadsheet are Dompdf, Mpdf, and Tcpdf.

```
$writer     =\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Tcpdf');
//$writer   =\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Dompdf');
//$writer   =\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Mpdf');
$pdf_path   ='output/tcpdf_output.pdf'; 
$writer->save($pdf_path);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a framework like codeigniter, you would need to load the TCPDF class using composer or in the config.php use $config['composer_autoload'] = [path of auto_config/ autoload].

You will also need to have the library of TCPDF. which you can get in 
https://github.com/tecnickcom/tcpdf